# Loading base 64 image strings with fresco is allocating too much memory

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, base64, fresco

I am using fresco to load images that I receive as a base 64 encoded string in a recyclerview, but the app is allocating too much memory (80+ mb)

Its straight forward to do that with that library, here is my adapter bind view holder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Empl empl= emplList.get(position);
    if (empl!= null && empl.getImage() != null) {
        String base64Encoding = empl.getImage();
        holder.draweeView.setImageURI(base64Encoding);
    }
}
```

Is there any pattern that I can follow to use less memory ?

The images are being loaded to a recyclerview and [image: App is allocating 70+mb]

Comment: How big are the images (dimensions) and what image format? Having them as a base64 encoded string is really not ideal since the String will take up unnecessary memory.

Comment: @AlexanderOprisnik ya it isn't, only thing I can do is to load them asynchronously for now